# Event control in always @(posedge clk)

Tags: verilog, fpga, synthesis

Wondering about the behavior of event control statements in an always block:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin: TEST
    ...
    @(wait_for_signal_from_subsystem);
    ... 
    @(wait_for_another_signal_from_subsystem);
    ...
end
```

Will the process be "stuck" until the event signals come in, or will it restart every time a clk edge comes in ?

Also is this synthesizable (Quartus II says yes, but not simulated yet...) ? and is this a good practice or is there an alternative better approach to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is 'stuck' as you would say. Only one 'loop' of the block can be active at a time, it will not reenter if it has not completed the loop.

The thing you are trying to do there is likely not synthesizable, due to the wait operations inside the block.

I don't know the exact specifics of your design, but I would approach this with a small finite state machine. I assume that the signals from your subsystem are not faster than the clock, so it would look something like:

```
always @* begin
  if(state_f == `WAIT_FOR_FIRST) 
       state_nxt = got_first_signal ? `WAIT_FOR_SECOND : `WAIT_FOR_FIRST;
  else if(state_f == `WAIT_FOR_SECOND)
       state_nxt = got_second_signal ? `DONE_STATE : `WAIT_FOR_SECOND;
  else if(state_f == `DONE_STATE) 
       state_nxt = `WAIT_FOR_FIRST;
  else
       state_nxt = 2'bxx;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    state_f <= state_nxt;
end
```

Comment: fsm is a good idea... just wanted to replicated "C/high level" style functionality in verilog/HDL ... but I guess you can't have everything :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are designing hardware and not non-synthesized testbench code, this not a good practice and likely won't do what you want anyways.

From a language perspective, this will compile and simulate. It **will** block waiting on the events within the always blocks and NOT restart on each posedge of the clock.  I could not find a spec reference for this but it's what I observed in simulation.  I'm curious what this would synthesize to if you even get it to synthesize with no errors.

---

If the signal from the other subsystem is already in the same clock domain (synchronous to `clk`), then you can just check the state of it on each clock edge, and use this do something.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin: TEST
  if (the_other_signal == 1'b1) begin
    ...
  end
end
```

Some other things to consider:

- Maybe you only care about when the signal assert/deasserts.  In that case you need to do an edge detection.
- If the signal is asynchronous to `clk`, then you have a clock domain crossing and you need to synchronize the incoming signal before you look at it.

Comment: Clock domain crossing is not a subject that can be explained in a comment box. :)  Here's a brief introduction: http://eetimes.com/design/eda-design/4018520/Understanding-Clock-Domain-Crossing-Issues